# Mockito version number on Terminal

Tags: java, intellij-idea, mockito, powermockito

Is there a way for me to find out which mockito version am I using using the terminal on my mac? Like I can find out the version on my IntelliJ IDE but the IDE is using Java 6 with Mockito and Powermock while, the backend where my code compiles, I have Java 8 using Mockito and Powermock which is causing problems with my tests. I checked Google threads for various results about checking which Mockito version I am using with Java 8 but I don't know a way to find out using my terminal.
For those who are interested in the stack trace, here is the stack trace.

```
Failed to transform class with name com.myproject.modcar.convertible.ConverterTest. Reason: java.io.IOException: invalid constant type: 18 at 1 

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to transform class with name com.myproject.modcar.convertible.ConverterTest. Reason: java.io.IOException: invalid constant type: 18 at 1
at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loaadMockClass(MockClassLoader.java:207)
at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadModifiedClass(MockClassLoader.java:145)
at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.MapMaker.make(MapMaker.java:193)

at javassist.bytecode.stackmap..MapMaker.make(MapMaker.java:193)
at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.MapMaker.make(MapMaker.java:193)
at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.MapMaker.make(MapMaker.java:193)
```

Comment: Are you using a build tool, like Gradle or Maven?

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave Im using Ant

Comment: OK, can you post your ant script? My point is that whatever version of a library you're using is being specified by you, somewhere, most likely in your bills script. As an aside, I'm interested in your setup, you'd make your life much easier if you kept your development environment in-line with your production environment.

Comment: Hey @DaveyDaveDave I think I found the problem. It was the problem with my javaassist jar misconfigured with Java 8 upgrade which broke my tests. It's like Java 8 needs a later version of Javaassist for mockito and other stuff to work. Thanks for the help though